# “llvm-config --libs all” return differently in apt package and Self-compiled. What is the library structure of LLVM？

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, llvm, static-libraries

```
# Self-compiled shared library
DESKTOP-BMR5HSI:/usr/local/llvm/bin$ ./llvm-config --libs all
-lLLVMWindowsManifest -lLLVMXRay -lLLVMLibDriver -lLLVMDlltoolDriver -lLLVMCoverage -lLLVMLineEditor -lLLVMXCoreDisassembler -lLLVMXCoreCodeGen -lLLVMXCoreDesc -lLLVMXCoreInfo -lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMWebAssemblyDisassembler -lLLVMWebAssemblyAsmParser -lLLVMWebAssemblyCodeGen -lLLVMWebAssemblyDesc -lLLVMWebAssemblyUtils -lLLVMWebAssemblyInfo -lLLVMSystemZDisassembler -lLLVMSystemZAsmParser -lLLVMSystemZCodeGen -lLLVMSystemZDesc -lLLVMSystemZInfo -lLLVMSparcDisassembler -lLLVMSparcAsmParser -lLLVMSparcCodeGen -lLLVMSparcDesc -lLLVMSparcInfo -lLLVMRISCVDisassembler -lLLVMRISCVAsmParser -lLLVMRISCVCodeGen -lLLVMRISCVDesc -lLLVMRISCVInfo -lLLVMPowerPCDisassembler -lLLVMPowerPCAsmParser -lLLVMPowerPCCodeGen -lLLVMPowerPCDesc -lLLVMPowerPCInfo -lLLVMNVPTXCodeGen -lLLVMNVPTXDesc -lLLVMNVPTXInfo -lLLVMMSP430Disassembler -lLLVMMSP430AsmParser -lLLVMMSP430CodeGen -lLLVMMSP430Desc -lLLVMMSP430Info -lLLVMMipsDisassembler -lLLVMMipsAsmParser -lLLVMMipsCodeGen -lLLVMMipsDesc -lLLVMMipsInfo -lLLVMLanaiDisassembler -lLLVMLanaiCodeGen -lLLVMLanaiAsmParser -lLLVMLanaiDesc -lLLVMLanaiInfo -lLLVMHexagonDisassembler -lLLVMHexagonCodeGen -lLLVMHexagonAsmParser -lLLVMHexagonDesc -lLLVMHexagonInfo -lLLVMBPFDisassembler -lLLVMBPFAsmParser -lLLVMBPFCodeGen -lLLVMBPFDesc -lLLVMBPFInfo -lLLVMAVRDisassembler -lLLVMAVRAsmParser -lLLVMAVRCodeGen -lLLVMAVRDesc -lLLVMAVRInfo -lLLVMARMDisassembler -lLLVMARMAsmParser -lLLVMARMCodeGen -lLLVMARMDesc -lLLVMARMUtils -lLLVMARMInfo -lLLVMAMDGPUTargetMCA -lLLVMAMDGPUDisassembler -lLLVMAMDGPUAsmParser -lLLVMAMDGPUCodeGen -lLLVMAMDGPUDesc -lLLVMAMDGPUUtils -lLLVMAMDGPUInfo -lLLVMAArch64Disassembler -lLLVMAArch64AsmParser -lLLVMAArch64CodeGen -lLLVMAArch64Desc -lLLVMAArch64Utils -lLLVMAArch64Info -lLLVMOrcJIT -lLLVMMCJIT -lLLVMJITLink -lLLVMInterpreter -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMRuntimeDyld -lLLVMOrcTargetProcess -lLLVMOrcShared -lLLVMDWP -lLLVMSymbolize -lLLVMDebugInfoPDB -lLLVMDebugInfoGSYM -lLLVMOption -lLLVMObjectYAML -lLLVMMCA -lLLVMMCDisassembler -lLLVMLTO -lLLVMPasses -lLLVMCFGuard -lLLVMCoroutines -lLLVMObjCARCOpts -lLLVMipo -lLLVMVectorize -lLLVMLinker -lLLVMInstrumentation -lLLVMFrontendOpenMP -lLLVMFrontendOpenACC -lLLVMExtensions -lLLVMDWARFLinker -lLLVMGlobalISel -lLLVMMIRParser -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMDebugInfoMSF -lLLVMDebugInfoDWARF -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMIRReader -lLLVMAsmParser -lLLVMInterfaceStub -lLLVMFileCheck -lLLVMFuzzMutate -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMAggressiveInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMBitWriter -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMProfileData -lLLVMObject -lLLVMTextAPI -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMMC -lLLVMDebugInfoCodeView -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMCore -lLLVMRemarks -lLLVMBitstreamReader -lLLVMBinaryFormat -lLLVMTableGen -lLLVMSupport -lLLVMDemangle

# apt package static library
DESKTOP-BMR5HSI:/usr/local/llvm/bin$ llvm-config --libs all
-lLLVM-13
```

Why is this different? Is it because the library types are different?

Is there any good documentation that can describe what each library represents?

I can use the add_llvm_executable macro in cmake to easily link the llvm library, but I would like to know what is going on behind it. Now llvm is completely a black box to me.

I hope someone can explain it to me or give me some high-quality documents. Reading LLVM's CMake module confuses me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late, but I've been getting this problem too. This solution works for me, but I'm not sure if it works for others or not.

You have to enable `LLVM_BUILD_LLVM_DYLIB` and `LLVM_LINK_LLVM_DYLIB`, and set `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` to 0 and **not NO**.